# Follow button with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I have created a button with which you can follow/unfollow a user, with AJAx and PHP.
If you click on the button, you follow, else, you unfollow.
There's a function that checks if the user you try to follow is already followed...

**HTML**

```
<div class="heart"><i class="fa fa-heart awesome"></i></div>
```

**PHP**

```
    public static function Follow($user, $seguidor){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO seguidores (id_canal, id_seguidor) VALUES ('$user', '$seguidor')";
        $resultado = self::Conexion($sql);
        return $resultado;
    }

    public static function CheckFollow($user, $seguidor){
        $heart = "";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM seguidores WHERE id_canal = '$user' AND id_seguidor= '$seguidor'";
        $resultado = self::Conexion($sql);
        $verificacion = false;

        if(isset($resultado)) {
            $fila = $resultado->fetch();
            if($fila !== false){
                $verificacion = true;
            }
        }

        if($verificacion == false){
            $heart = "<div data-id='".$user."' class='heart'><i class='fa fa-heart awesome'></i></div>";
        } else {
            $heart = "<div data-id='".$user."' class='heart like'><i class='fa fa-heart awesome'></i></div>";
        }
        return $heart;
    }

    public static function Unfollow($user, $seguidor){
        $sql = "DELETE FROM seguidores WHERE id_canal = '$user' AND id_seguidor= '$seguidor'";
        $resultado = self::Conexion($sql);
        return $resultado;
    }
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var data_id = element.attr("data-id");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "database.php",
            data: data_id,
            success: function(){ }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

The problem is, how can I load those php funcionts everytime I click the button...

**Click** > follow

**Another click** > unfollow

Comment: Look create follow unfollow functionality for login user , if user follow someone then hide the follow button and show unfollow button  for that particular logged in user.

Comment: That's not the way I want to do it :S. When you follow someone, `.heart` receives another class called `.like`, then, the div turns orange, else, black...

Comment: Here you go [Creating Twitter Like Follow System Using PHP](http://www.meralesson.com/2016/02/creating-twitter-like-follow-system-php-jquery.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few suggestions:

I notice you are creating HTML strings in PHP. If at all possible, you want to avoid doing that.

Keep all your HTML, CSS and JavaScript client-side. As you progress as a developer, you will start to see why. Think of them as templates.

In this case, you just need to return either "followed" or 'unfollowed" to the client callback. Could boil it down to a boolean!

So, in your template, define both the followed state and the unfollowed state. Use CSS to hide the appropriate one. This can be incredibly lightweight!

In these examples, you just set the follow attribute on your button.

So your javascript would look like:

```
// I would do something like:
find=document;
id="getElementById";

/* ... */

success: function (request, status)
{   
    if (!status)
        return
    ;

    find[id]("follow-1").setAttribute("follow", request.responseText)
}
```

(check the ajax api of the lib)

1.)

```
<button id="follow-1" follow="true">
 <img src="transparent.png" />
</button>
```

+

```
button[follow="false"] > img
{ background: transparent url("unfollow.png");
}
button[follow="true"] > img
{ background: transparent url("follow.png");
}
```

2.)

```
<button id="follow-1" follow="true">
 <img src="follow.png" />
 <img src="unfollow.png" />
</button>
```

+

```
button[follow] > img
{ display: none;
}
button[follow="false"] > img:last-child
{ display: block;
}
button[follow="true"] > img:first-child
{ display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using framework such as CodeIgniter to handle the back-end as you can post data directly to public controller methods directly from ajax, but for rough idea on how it could work (you may need to fix up bugs / tweak as I wrote from memory):

**Add to PHP to handle incoming requests:**

```
//Minimal vulnerability protection while getting inputs.
$update_types = array("Follow", "CheckFollow", "Unfollow");
$update_method = in_array($_POST["update_type"], 
                        $update_types)? $_POST["update_type"], "");

if ($update_method) {
    //Call the update function & bounce the response
    //in JSON back to the AJAX handler.
    echo json_encode(call_user_func($update_method, 
         (int) $_POST["user_id"], (int) $_POST["seguidor"]));
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

    //Button click handler.
    $("div.heart").on("click", function() {
       var my_button = $(this);
       var update_type = "";

       if (my_button.hasClass('.like'))
           update_type = "Unfollow";
       else
           update_type = "Follow";

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "database.php",
           data: {
                  "update_type": update_type,
                  user_id: my_button.attr("data-id"),
                  seguidor: "some value here - not sure based on code"
           },
           success: function(response) {   
             //response from server - check for errors...
             //Update the UI - add heart if follow updated, remove it if not.
             //You will need to modify your php functions to return result code and then either add "like" class or remove it - obviously this is not a complete rewrite of your app.
             if ("/* result is followed */")
               my_button.addClass("like");
             else
                my_button.removeClass("like");
           }
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: `seguidor` is the user with whom you follow some channel. That variable should return the value off the session that someone is using when he follows someone.

Comment: This answer is well thought-out because it has the ability to toggle, except for one simple problem: the original state of the button is "unlike" by default. Only once clicked does it toggle and then reflect the real state. I would just slightly change it by defining just 1 ajax method and (1) calling it once on page load to show the correct default state (2) call it each time it is clicked. Simply in case 1 or 2 just pass an extra boolean through the POST with the ajax to tell the server if it should toggle; case 1 is no / case 2 is always yes.

Comment: However, you can still do it the way in your answer, but only if you have the PHP dynamically fill in the default "like" class on the button's html when serving the page itself. However, since the "like/unlike" feature is intended already to be such a frequently used and programmatically trivial one, filling in the defaults on the client-side with ajax is the overall full-stack, less-hassle, straight-forward approach.